# how to combine two lists?

Tags: python, list, merge

I have 2 lists

```
mylist1 = [ 23,   13, None, 65,   None, 966, None, None]
mylist2 = [ None, 13, 98,   None, 61,   966, 13,   2]
```

I need to merge these two lists into

```
[ 23,   13, 98, 65,   61, 966, 13, 2]
```

any nice solution?

--

Solution I've chosen, thanks @shaktimaan

```
mylist = [(a if a!=None else b) for a, b in zip(mylist1, mylist2)]
```

Comment: What happens if the two lists disagree? `[None, 2]` and `[1, 3]`

Comment: Where did `96` come from in your output?  Shouldn't it be `98`?

Comment: What have *you tried* so far?

Comment: How do you decide what goes in the resulting list? eg what would the result be for @delnan

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is ORing of corresponding numbers in the two lists, this is one way you can get the output list:

```
>>> mylist1 = [ 23,   13, None, 65,   None, 966, None, None]
>>> mylist2 = [ None, 13, 98,   None, 61,   966, 13,   2]
>>> mylis1 = [a if a else 0 for a in mylist1 ]
>>> mylis1
[23, 13, 0, 65, 0, 966, 0, 0]
>>> mylis2 = [a if a else 0 for a in mylist2 ]
>>> mylis2
[0, 13, 98, 0, 61, 966, 13, 2]
>>> output = [a | b for a, b in zip(mylis1, mylis2)]
>>> output
[23, 13, 98, 65, 61, 966, 13, 2]
```

Comment: thanks that's nice, that's what I was looking for.
mylist = [(a if a!=None else b) for a, b in zip(mylist1, mylist2)]

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the built-in `map` function. `map` applies a function to each element of one or more lists. For example:

```
>>> def addOne(x):
...     return x+1
... 
>>> map(addOne, [1, 2, 3, 4])
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

With two lists and a lambda function:

```
>>> map(lambda x,y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5])
[3, 5, 7, 9]
```

So you just need to do:

```
combined_list = map(combine_function, mylist1, mylist2)
```

Comment: FYI `map(f, zip(a, b))` can more easily be written as `map(f, a, b)`. It's not precisely equivalent (it passes two arguments instead of a single tuple) but in most cases that's an improvement.

Comment: Yeah... just remembered about that.

Comment: Thanks, the map function seems very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
for i, n in enumerate(mylist1): mylist2[i]=mylist2[i] or n
```

If both lists have a value (a different one) for the same position, the one in `mylist2` will be chosen.

You can swap the lists to give preference to `mylist1` or you can use `max`, `min` or some other function to chose between different values:

```
for i, n in enumerate(mylist1): mylist2[i]=max(mylist2[i], n)
```

If both have `None` in a given position, it will be preserved in the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it elaborately:

```
mylist1 = [ 23,   13, None, 65,   None, 966, None, None]
mylist2 = [ None, 13, 98,   None, 61,   966, 13,   2]
newList = []

if len(mylist1)>len(mylist2):
    length = len(mylist1)
else:
    length = len(mylist2)

for i in range(length):
    if mylist1[i] and i<len(mylist1):
        newList.append(mylist1[i])
    if mylist2[i] and i<len(mylist2) and mylist2[i] != mylist1[i]:
        newList.append(mylist2[i])

print newList
```

It printed:

```
[23, 13, 98, 65, 61, 966, 13, 2]
```